# SQLite reads small decimal values as 0?

Tags: c#, sqlite, decimal

I have a sqlite table with "very small values" in one column. Like 0.00000363455000.
When I run a query in "DB Browser for SQlite" the values are shown correct:

Screenshot DB Browser for SQlite 1

[image: Screenshot DB Browser for SQlite 1]

In my c# application the small values are always 0.

```
            using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(
                    "Data Source='" + dmaDataSource + "'"))
            {
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
                connection.Open();
                SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    response = new DmaResponse();
                    
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Type t0 = reader.GetFieldType(0); // is decimal
                        Type t1 = reader.GetFieldType(1); // is decimal
                        string f0 = reader.GetName(0);
                        string f1 = reader.GetName(1);

                        response.price_per_ton = (decimal)reader[0];
                        string test = reader[1].ToString(); // "0"
                        response.price_per_mm3 = (decimal)reader[1]; // 0.00000363455000 becomes 0
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: Screenshot Comparison DB Browser / VS Debug]

Any Ideas?

After some more tests:
Both fields are type of NUMERIC:
[image]
which is decimal in c#.

I tried the GetDecimal method before I created this post.

```
response.price_per_ton = reader.GetDecimal(0);
string test = reader[1].ToString();
response.price_per_mm3 = reader.GetDecimal(1);
```

GetDecimal(0) works, GetDecimal(1) throwed an exception:
{"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Then I used DB Browser to change the decimal separator in "my" row form , to .
[image]

Now, reader.GetDecimal(1) doesn't throw an exception anymore, but gives back 0.

Comment: Hello could you try with float or double instead of decimal. I think it is getting 0 because of casting to decimal.

Comment: What is the value if you get as string?

Comment: Did you check that there isn't a mismatch between decimal points stored vs decimal point expected ?  SQLite isn't typed, so you could easily store as "0,01" while your program expects "0.01" for math.

Comment: McNets: The string is "0".

Comment: Atahan Ceylan: The database field type is NUMERIC which is decimal in c#. Casting reader(1) to double throws an exeption.

Comment: I'm guessing the value is actually a string, probably because of the comma. SQLite mostly ignores the column type anyway, you can store different types in the same column.

Comment: What if you use `GetValue` what data type and value do you get?

Comment: SQLITE [doesn't have a `decimal` type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) only a 64-bit REAL. That's the size of `double`. You gain nothing by using `GetDecimal` to retrieve 128 bits - the underlying value simply isn't that precise.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation of sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_blob.html), the fundamental data types are:

- 64-bit signed integer
- 64-bit IEEE floating point number
- string
- BLOB
- NULL

In your case, it would be a 64-bit IEEE floating point number.

The Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core library (note that I am assuming you are using this), [uses decimal.Parse on the result of GetString](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/8a8105d31879d435271848a595d5b7ec31ef6ce5/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteValueReader.cs#L90) if you use GetDecimal on the reader.

This means that the field is retrieved as a string, causing an auto-convert of the value from numeric to text, and then a conversion back to a number with decimal.Parse. This has lots of ways that it could go wrong.

If you use GetDouble, the native method sqlite_column_double is used in the driver, and there will be no conversions (and I expect therefore no invalid formats).

A double is less precise than a decimal, so you'd probably want to convert the double to decimal before doing calculations with it.

For the smallest possible margin of error, store the decimals as a string in the database, that way you avoid any auto-convert (but will use more bytes to store the same data).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting closer to it:

```
ServerVersion = "3.37.0"
```

`Column[1]` is type of `System.Decimal` and the expected value is `0.00000363455000`.
`reader[1].ToString()` returns `"0"`
`(decimal) reader[1]`  returns `0`
`reader.GetDecimal(1)` throws an exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

`reader.GetString(1)` returns `"0,00000363455000"` (German decimal separator)
which I can cast to decimal.

Now I have my expected value but I don't know why.

Comment: GetDecimal is basically a GetString followed by a `Decimal.Parse`: 
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/8a8105d31879d435271848a595d5b7ec31ef6ce5/src/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/SqliteValueReader.cs#L90

GetString calls: 
sqlite3_column_text(Handle, ordinal).utf8_to_string()

Which takes the text from the column as-is, perhaps it's possible to get sqlite to return a numeric value properly.

Comment: SQLite has only a 64-bit REAL type. Use `GetDouble()` instead of `GetDecimal()`. GetDouble  uses `sqlite3_column_double` to read the actual `double` value

Comment: You should update your question instead of posting this as an answer.

Comment: As for why `decimal` is mapped to text and parsed, it's because it's not possible to use `REAL` to store 128-bit decimals. The only alternative is to store them as text. The `InvariantCulture` is used to ensure the string isn't affected by localized decimal separators